# I'm trying to print out the lines in a file, but without the "\n"s

Tags: python

[The code and its output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAXNV.png)
It doesn't seem to be working and I don't understand why.

```
myFile.close()
myFile2 = open('Twitter_Sayings.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")

newline = "\n"
fileLines = myFile2.readlines()
for line in fileLines:
    print(line)
  if newline in line:
    line.replace("\n", "")
print(fileLines)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python and, hence, all methods that modify a string return a new string object and do not mutate the original. Then you have to replace the originals by those new strings in the list:

```
# you need the index, as rebinding the loop variable 'line' won't affect the list
for i in range(len(fileLines)):
    # use return value and put it back in the list
    fileLines[i] = fileLines[i].replace("\n", "")  
print(fileLines)
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to deal with this is with the `rstrip` method.

```
with myFile2 = open('Twitter_Sayings.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as myFile2:
    for line in myFile2:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        # Other processing
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` strips the newline character from the lines you are reading, but 
 `print` prints its own newline. If you don't want the newline, you should use `print(line, end='')`.

In addition:

- `line.replace("\n", "")` is not effective, first because `readlines` won't produce strings with newlines in them, and second because `replace` returns a new string which you're not storing anywhere.
- `print(fileLines)` will print the "repr" (representation) of `fileLines`; this will include the array syntax, string delimiters, and so on and look like `['line 1', 'line 2', ...]`.